# A way to interrupt a macro at certain moments

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I'm making a VBA macro that generates random numbers to find the most distant points on a cube. It works, but it often stumbles along for too long while doing nothing of any value, so I need to interrupt the macro sometimes.

However, I only want to interrupt at a certain moment, and the normal Ctrl+Break keyboard shortcut can interrupt the macro in the middle of a process, which can muck up the coordinate values I'm using. So I want a method to interrupt a macro at certain moments, preferably with a key press.

If needed, here is the code:

```
Sub optimize()
Dim Distance As Double
Dim OldNumber As Double
Dim OldNumbers(1 To 3) As Double
Dim l As Double
Dim n As Integer
Dim m As Integer
Distance = Range("H14").Value 'This cell contains the distance between the closest 2 points in the coordinates, using =MIN()
l = 0
LoopIt:
l = l + 1
For n = 0 To 7
For m = 0 To 2 'The coordinates are stored at F4:H11.
OldNumber = Range("F4").Offset(n, m).Value
If Rnd() > 0.01 Then
Range("F4").Offset(n, m).Value = OldNumber + Rnd() / 10000 - 0.00005 'Just slighty nudge the values...
Else
Range("F4").Offset(n, m).Value = Rnd() '...but only sometimes.
End If
If Range("F4").Offset(n, m).Value > 1 Then Range("F4").Offset(n, m).Value = 1
If Range("F4").Offset(n, m).Value < 0 Then Range("F4").Offset(n, m).Value = 0 'Making sure the values don't go too high or low
If Range("H14").Value >= Distance Then 'Are the closest points as far away as before? If so, that's Ok.
    If Range("H14").Value > Distance Then 'Are the closest points further away? If so, reset counter.
    l = 0
    End If
Distance = Range("H14").Value
Else 'Are the closest points closer? If so, reset.
Range("F4").Offset(n, m).Value = OldNumber
End If
Next m
OldNumbers(1) = Range("F4").Offset(n, 0).Value
OldNumbers(2) = Range("F4").Offset(n, 1).Value
OldNumbers(3) = Range("F4").Offset(n, 2).Value
Range("F4").Offset(n, 0).Value = Rnd()
Range("F4").Offset(n, 1).Value = Rnd()
Range("F4").Offset(n, 2).Value = Rnd() 'I don't know why I put this in, but it might become useful sometime.
If Range("H14").Value >= Distance Then 'Are the closest points as far away as before? If so, that's Ok.
    If Range("H14").Value > Distance Then 'Are the closest points further away? If so, reset counter.
    l = 0
    End If
Distance = Range("H14").Value
Else 'Are the closest points closer? If so, reset.
Range("F4").Offset(n, 0).Value = OldNumbers(1)
Range("F4").Offset(n, 1).Value = OldNumbers(2)
Range("F4").Offset(n, 2).Value = OldNumbers(3)
End If
Next n
'I only want to interrupt here.
If l > 10000 Then 'Has it found nothing for so long? Then quit.
'I sometimes adjust the barrier l needs to hit to very high values so it can compute on its own for a long ass-time without any input.
MsgBox ("Done!")
Exit Sub
End If
GoTo LoopIt
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VoG of MrExcel seems to have [a nice answer](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/350685-stopping-macro-keystroke.html#post1732808).

```
Type KeyboardBytes
    kbb(0 To 255) As Byte
End Type

Declare Function GetKeyboardState Lib "User32.DLL" (kbArray As KeyboardBytes) As Long

Sub StartLotteryDraw()
Dim kbArray As KeyboardBytes
Application.Cursor = xlWait
Do
    Calculate
    DoEvents
    GetKeyboardState kbArray
    If kbArray.kbb(32) And 128 Then
        Application.Cursor = xlNormal
        Exit Sub
    End If
Loop
End Sub
```

For your case, put this check at the end of your code, or if each iteration of the code takes so long that it doesn't detect your keypress, add a few checks throughout the code and use it to set a variable, then test for the variable at the end.

For example:

```
Type KeyboardBytes
    kbb(0 To 255) As Byte
End Type

Declare Function GetKeyboardState Lib "User32.DLL" (kbArray As KeyboardBytes) As Long
```

Add this line to your var declarations:

```
Dim doInterrupt As Boolean
```

Place this line 3-4 places in your code, evenly spaced relative to how long the preceding code takes to execute:

```
If doInterrupt = False Then doInterrupt = CheckInterrupt
```

Modify this part of your code:

```
If l > 10000 Then
```

to something like this:

```
If l > 1000000 Or doInterrupt = True Then
```

Finally, add this function after your code:

```
Function CheckInterrupt() As Boolean
    Dim kb As KeyboardBytes
    GetKeyboardState kb

    If kb.kbb(32) And 128 Then CheckInterrupt = True
End Function
```